# PHP - Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Too must be an instance of Foo, instance of Boo given?

Tags: php, inheritance

I don't quite understand the benefits of indicating the class name you would inject into another class, such as,

```
public function __construct(Foo $Foo)
```

I can see its benefits in this case,

```
class Foo
{
    public $message = 'foo';
}

class Boo 
{
    public $message = 'boo';
}

class Too
{
    public function __construct(Foo $Foo)
    {
        $this->Foo = $Foo;
    }

    public function fetch()
    {
        return $this->Foo->message;
    }
}

$Too = new Too(new Boo);
var_dump($Too->fetch());
```

I will get this error,

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Too::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Foo, instance of Boo given, called in C:...

But if I change

```
class Boo
{
    public $message = 'boo';
}
```

to

```
class Boo extends Foo
{
    public $message = 'boo';
}
```

I will get the correct result, without an error,

```
string 'boo' (length=3)
```

But, the meaning or semantic of `Foo $Foo` has broken down. because I am passing `$Boo` in actually.

The semantic of `$this->Foo->message;` is gone too because I am reading `$message` in `$Boo` now. but this `$this->Foo->message;` saying I am reading `$message` in `$Foo`...

Is it a flaw in PHP? Otherwise how would you explain that? Is this happening in other languages (like Java or Python) as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will happen in all languages as it is part of OOP.
the actual use of it would be having a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) as an example.

```
interface Mammal
{
    public function walk();
}

class Human implements Mammal
{
    public function walk()
    {
        echo 'Walk using two legs or whatever';
    }
}

class Cat implements Mammal
{
    public function walk()
    {
        echo 'Walk using four legs or whatever';
    }
}

function performWalk(Mammal $mammal){
   $mammal->walk();
}
```

Now the concept is that I asked for a Mammal and I don't care if it is Human or a cat or anything else, as it is not the class responsibility to know about what kind of implementation does that Mammal have.

Therefore, to answer your question >>>> It is not a bug, it is a feature :) <<<<<

Comment: Aww that makes sense. so `$mammal->walk();` will echo the `walk` in  `Human` or `Cat`?

Comment: as a performWalk function, you don't really care. whoever is calling that function have the responsibility to know what instance it needs to pass to performWalk

Answer (score 3):

The class being passed in must meet the requirements of Foo.  If Boo extends Foo, PHP considers Boo as meeting all the requirements of Foo.  Not all languages will also accept a class that inherits the called for class, but this is true in PHP.  Often, people will implement an interface and the class can accept any class that implements the interface.   This way, should you decide your original class Foo is broken, you could replace it with another class that implements the same interface.

If you wanted to pass in Boo and Boo was in no way related to Foo, then Too should be defined with the constructor public function __construct(Boo $Boo) otherwise you are not using it for how it was intended.

I hope that helps.